# ¿Por qué se borra la primera oración de mi publicación?

Tags: soporte, estado-por-diseño, ediciones

[Esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23634/en-el-dle-hay-m%c3%a1s-casos-de-acepciones-tan-localizadas-regionalmente-como-la-5%c2%aa/23640#23640) empezaba así:

> Hay más. Acá van algunas.

Pero cuando grabé, vi que me había borrado el “Hay más.”. Edité, lo agregué, volví a grabar: me lo volvió a borrar. Intenté otra vez y lo mismo.

¿Qué está pasando?

Comment: Para futura referencia, veo que el OP ha cosultado en Meta.SE: [Should the word “hay” not be deleted at the beginning of posts, especially in the Spanish SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996/209901).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este es un bonito e interesante bug que tiene *cierto* sentido.

**Resumiendo**: todo lo que hay desde el principio en "Hay" hasta el primer punto, se elimina porque el sistema lo identifica como un saludo.

---

En [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/209901) se comentaba que hay muchas preguntas con cabeceras del tipo "Hola", etc, y que la gente estaba cansada de eliminarlas.

Por ello, el fundador de Stack Overflow, Jeff Atwood, [contestó](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/209901) dándole la razón e indicando que a partir de ese momento se implementaría una eliminación automática de ciertas frases si se encuentran al principio de una publicación:

> We now automatically remove *salutations* from posts as they are entered.
>
> I got really tired of performing this edit over and over, so anything matching the form of …
>
> ```
> ^                 # begins at start of body
> \s*               # possible spaces
> (
> hii?(?![a-z])|    # any of these greeting words
> hello|
> h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|
> dear|
> greetings|
> hai|
> guys|
> howdy|
> h(i|e)ya|
> hola
> )
> .*?               # followed by anything, up to...
> (
> [.,;!-]+          # one or more bits of punctuation
> \s*               # possible spaces
> |
> (\r?\n)+          # one or more newlines
> )
> ```
>
> … is removed automagically at the time of submission to the server.

En tu caso concreto, escribiste "Hay...", lo que en inglés se entendería como un saludo y tiene la mala suerte de [coincidir](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/21218/1674) con la expresión regular:

```
^                 # begins at start of body
\s*               # possible spaces
(
h(e|a)y(?![a-z])|
)
.*?               # followed by anything, up to...
(
[.,;!-]+          # one or more bits of punctuation
\s*               # possible spaces
|
(\r?\n)+          # one or more newlines
)
```

---

**Solución**: En lugar de "Hay...", usa algo tipo "Existe" o similar.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, que no sé cómo pudiste encontrar. _Hats off!_ Un detalle: creo que sí es un bug, y merece el tag, ya que "hay" es una palabra perfectamente válida tanto en español como en inglés. En cambio, como saludo es poco o nada usada. Parece más bien una previsión innecesaria (¿y si ponen "a" en vez de "e"?) por parte de Atwood.

Comment: Es que ya me encontré con algo parecido [hace un tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1531/83) :) Además, soy ávido lector de Meta.SE, siempre se descubren cosas majas.

Comment: Yo creo que no es bug sino funcionalidad, pues la cosa está funcionando tal y como tienen documentado. Lo que está claro es que no es práctico y que deberían adaptar estas eliminaciones al idioma en el que está redactada la publicación, [aunque actualmente no tienen cómo hacerlo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325865/325866#comment539427_325866). Sea como fuere, está claro que esto está mal. Lo que recomendaría es abrir un feature-request en Meta.SE solicitando que esta eliminación de saludos sea específica de cada sitio.

Comment: @walen tienes razón, no lo recordaba. Acabo de compilar toda la información y comentarlo en [Let's make the automatic removal of salutations language specific!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305125/209901)

Answer (score 0):

El autor de esta pregunta pidió en Meta Stack Exchange que se dejara de eliminar este saludo: [Should the word “hay” not be deleted at the beginning of posts, especially on Spanish SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304996/209901).

Observo que esto ha llevado a que un desarrollador haya decidido eliminar este saludo de la lista:

> starting with the next build, we won't treat "hay" as a salutation. [<sub>comentario de Adam Lear</sub>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304996/should-the-word-hay-not-be-deleted-at-the-beginning-of-posts-especially-on-sp#comment992479_305336)

Por lo que la petición pasa a figurar como [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).